# Why are all my downstream Airflow tasks skipped?

Tags: airflow

I have this branchpython operator. I checked from the log it returns end_task task. But instead of end_task is marked as success, it is marked as skipped? why is that? This is my first time using branch operator. I saw from reference my code should be right but it even skip the returned task.
[image]

My code

```
END = EmptyOperator(task_id="end_task")

def missing_check():
        SQL = f"""
        ...
        """
        big_query_hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id=BIGQUERY_STG_CONN, use_legacy_sql=False)

        df = big_query_hook.get_pandas_df(SQL, dialect="standard")
        if any(df['num_missing_ids'] != 0):
            return 'diff_email_notif'
        else:
            return 'end_task'

missing_data_check = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='missing_data_check',
        python_callable=missing_check,
)

START >> processing >> fact_cx_daily_log >> missing_data_check
missing_data_check >> email_notif >> END
missing_data_check >> END
```

The log

```
[2023-10-11, 12:34:26 UTC] {python.py:183} INFO - Done. Returned value was: end_task
[2023-10-11, 12:34:26 UTC] {python.py:216} INFO - Branch callable return end_task
[2023-10-11, 12:34:26 UTC] {skipmixin.py:164} INFO - Following branch end_task
[2023-10-11, 12:34:26 UTC] {skipmixin.py:224} INFO - Skipping tasks ['diff_email_notif']
[2023-10-11, 12:34:26 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1345} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=re_cx_daily_log_v3, task_id=missing_data_check, execution_date=20231011T123255, start_date=20231011T123423, end_date=20231011T123426
[2023-10-11, 12:34:27 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-10-11, 12:34:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define task `end_task` as downstream task for `missing_data_check`. [Documentation for `trigger_rule`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator) attribute says: *default is `all_success`* So it will start TI if **all** of its upstream TIs are in `success` state, which is not true for skipped branch.

Use `none_failed_min_one_success` rule for such cases. See details in [Tasks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/tasks.html#task-instances) paragraph.